# How to combine multiple answers on Matlab onto a list?

Tags: matlab

I'm sure this is obvious but I couldn't find the solution on the internet...

in Matlab when I do this:

```
> list = dir('some_directory');
> list

list = 
  3×1 struct array with fields:
  name
  folder
  date
  bytes
  isdir
  datenum
```

I want to store all file names on a list. If I call *list.name* I just get multiple answers

```
> list.name
ans =
some_file_1.mat

ans =
some_file_2.mat

ans =
some_file_3.mat
```

I tried this but it didn't work

```
> dirlist = list.name
ans =
some_file_1.mat
```

then I tried this and it didn't work

```
> dirlist = [list.name]
ans =
some_file_1.matsome_file_2.matsome_file_3.mat
```

Answer (score 4):

You can store the list in cells:

```
dirlist = {list.name};
```

You can then call each individual entry like this:

```
dirlist{1};
...
dirlist{20};
etc..
```

Edit:
Alternatively you could also access the individual elements of the initial structure:

```
list(1).name;
...
list(20).name;
etc...
```

You could even save the variable `name` in a new structure containing only this variable:

```
dirlist = struct('name',{list.name});
```

Comment: solved my problem but I still feel I don't understand why the different behavior for the list and cell case in matlab

Comment: the variable `list` is, in this case, a structure.
If you want to access the different elements of the structure, you need to call the entry of the structure.
So if you want to access entry one:
`list(1).name`
would produce the first entry.
You could therefore work with that instead of the cell, or even save the structure of _name_ in a new structure without the fields that you don't need.
What you tried with the vector does not work because strings have different length, which can not be aggregated into a matrix